# Node.js 3rd party API call using Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

Im using express with node.js & having trouble consuming data from this free api `https://api.publicapis.org/entries?category=animals&https=true` any feedback will be helpful!

This code outputs the following error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

```
 request({
    method: 'GET',
    host: 'https://api.publicapis.org',
    path:  '/entries?category=animals&https=true',
 }, function (error, response, body){
    const data = response.body;
    const apiData = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log('Returned: ', apiData)
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      res.json(body);
    }
    else{
      console.log("error with api call")
    }
 })
```

Comment: response is null, therefore body is not there. may i ask why there is htt is your host path? if you delete it you get a response as far as i can see

Comment: Posting the URL in the browser (not node.js) gives me this result: `server failed to parse request: schema: invalid path "htt"`

Comment: My guess is all you need to do is remove `&htt` from the end because https://api.publicapis.org/entries?category=animals (without `htt`) returns JSON data

Comment: @MücahidErenler My bad, I didnt copy the path correctly to this question. This is the url https://api.publicapis.org/entries?category=animals&https=true and with the correct url I still get a 'Cannot read property 'body' of undefined' when running the code

Comment: @slebetman I didnt copy the url correctly to this question, my mistake. The host I'm using in my code is 'https://api.publicapis.org' and path '/entries?category=animals&https=true'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your exact code, I get an error in the `error` parameter.  That's why both `response` and `body` are empty.  You have an error.  The specific error is this:

```
Error: options.uri is a required argument
    at Request.init (D:\code\test\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:231:31)
    at new Request (D:\code\test\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
    at request (D:\code\test\temp\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\code\test\temp\temp.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Always check for errors before you try to use the other parameters and log any errors and it will save you a lot of time.

---

If you change to this, it works for me:

```
const request = require('request');

request({
   method: 'GET',
   uri: 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries?category=animals&https=true',
}, function (error, response, body){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
   const data = response.body;
   const apiData = JSON.parse(data)
   console.log('Returned: ', apiData)
   if(response.statusCode == 200){
     console.log('success');
   }
   else{
     console.log("error with api call")
   }
});
```

Several things to note:

1. The `request()` library has been deprecated.  While it will be maintained for a while (perhaps a long while), it will not be enhanced with new features any more.  There's a list of alternatives that are still being actively developed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  I'm using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) because it seems very nice and simple and quick to use and it entirely promise-based.
2. Always check for errors and log them before you try to use any of the other arguments.  That will save you a ton of debugging time.
3. When sending with `res.json()`, you should pass it a Javascript object, not already converted JSON.  Since you already have that with `data`, that's what I changed your call to.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I ran the changes you made & I'm getting the following error 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.publicapis.org'

Comment: @CatGirl19 - I don't know what to say.  When I run this code exactly as it shows here as a stand-alone program, it works.